# Mongodb: which datatype must be used in Mongoose schema to store null and ObjectId of the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The schema I am using for category collection looks like:

```
{
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  parent: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }
}
```

Now, for all level-1 categories, I want to store parent as `null` and for level-2 and so on will be storing `ObjectId` of the parent document. How to define this condition in schema? I can not use type `String` as it will not allow me to map to parent document whenever required. Any other solution for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  parent: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default: null }
}
```

Setting the default key as `null` might help... if value not inserted it defaults to `null`.